# How do I create a shortcode that returns a logged in users' email?

Tags: shortcode

So far I have this:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

function shortcode_get_email() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id <> 0) {
        return $current_user->user_email;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_get_user_email', 'shortcode_get_email' );
```

It doesn't seem to return the email of the logged in user. It returns nothing, supposedly an empty string.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to move `wp_get_current_user()` inside of the shortcode's callback (untested):

```php
function current_user_email_address() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '';
    }

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return esc_html( $user->user_email );
}
add_shortcode( 'current_user_email_address', 'current_user_email_address' );
```